# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently trying to fit some parameters to an existing data file. After adding a fitting routine I keep getting the `'TypeError: '*numpy.float64' object is not iterable*'` error, which seems to have something to do with the Dl  function that i defined. I haven't been able to solve this myself, so I'd be really grateful for any tips concerning this matter.

```
import pylab as p
import scipy as s
from scipy.integrate import odeint,quad
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

z = np.arange(0.00, 1.5, 0.02)
z1, m1, sigma_m = np.loadtxt('data.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0,1,2])
yerr = sigma_m


def H(z,omega_m,H0):
    return H0*p.sqrt(omega_m*(1+z)**3+1-omega_m)


def Dl(z,omega_m,H0):
    c = 3*10**5
    y = []
    for i in z:
        y1 = c*(1+i)*quad(f,0.0,i, args=(omega_m,H0))[0]
        y.append(y1)
    return p.asarray(y)


def f(z,omega_m,H0):
    return 1./H(z,omega_m,H0)


def m(z,omega_m,H0,M):
    q = []
    for j in Dl(z,omega_m,H0):
        q1 = M+5*np.log10(j)+25.0
        q.append(q1)
    return p.asarray(q)


def chi2(omega_m, M):
    return sum((m(z1,omega_m,70,M)-m1)/sigma_m)**2

chi2_min=1*10**30
o = np.arange(0.00, 1.5, 0.02)
Mrange = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.02)

for omega_m in o:
    for M in Mrange:
        if chi2(omega_m, M) < chi2_min:
            omega_min=omega_m
            M_min=M
            chi2_min=m(omega_min, M_min, 70, M)

print(M_min)
print(chi2_min)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your routine `Dl`, the iteration over z is invalid. z is a scalar at each invokation.

Transform your program so that either Dl is given an array or remove the loop in Dl.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be here:

`chi2_min=m(omega_min, M_min, 70, M)`

`omega_min` is a float, which gets passed to `Dl()` in `m()` here:

`for j in Dl(z,omega_m,H0):`

and then `Dl()` tries to iterate it:

`for i in z:`

which raises your error

To fix, I recommend you pass `omega_min` as a list:

`chi2_min=m([omega_min], M_min, 70, M)`