# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable :(

Tags: python-3.x

I have written the following code and i keep getting errors. Can anyone help me find the mistake? The function roundGrade is a function i have above my code and it works fine.

I want find the mean of the numbers (final grade) but there are some conditions. There are N students and they have made M assignments. If M = 1, then the final grade should be the grade of that one assignment. If M > 1, then the lowest grade should be removed and the final grade should be the mean of the grades. If one of the grades is -3, then the final grade should be -3. these 3 conditions should apply to my code..

```
def computeFinalGrades(grades):
    g = grades
    g2 = np.zeros(np.size(g[:,1]))

    for i in range(np.size(g2)):
        g3 = roundGrade(g[i,:])

        if np.any(g3) == -3:
            grade = -3
        elif np.size(g3) == 1:
            grade = g[0]
        elif np.size(g3) > 1:
            g4 = heapq.nlargest(np.size(g-1),g3)
            grade = roundGrade(np.mean(g4))
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again")
            g2[i] = grade

        gradesFinal = g2
        return gradesFinal

x = np.array([[1,2,-3,6],[2,3,9,0],[-3,4,8,7]])
print(computeFinalGrades(x))     


  File "C:/Users/Ambro/Desktop/project2grades.py", line 50, in computeFinalGrades
    grade = roundGrade(np.mean(g4))

  File "C:/Users/Ambro/Desktop/project2grades.py", line 14, in roundGrade
    for i in grades:

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034829/typeerror-numpy-float64-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: i dont get it.. i have tried but can't find my mistake..please help me

Comment: Reading through your stack trace, it says you’re trying to iterate through something that is not a list in roundgrades(). Can you post your code for roundgrades()?